# Web scraping : not able to scrape text and href for a given div, class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to get the text and href for top news but not able to parse it.

website : [News site](https://www.gujaratsamachar.com/)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def checkResponse(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.content
    else:
        return None


def getTitleURL():
    url = 'https://www.gujaratsamachar.com/'
    response = checkResponse(url)
    if response is not None:
        html = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

    for values in html.find_all('div', class_='main-news'):
        print(values.a.href)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Getting the list of names....')
    names = getTitleURL()
    print('... done.\n')
```

> Output is empty

Trying to scrape the part in red:

[image]

Elements looks like this:

[image]

Comment: The content is loaded dynamically to the page with JavaScript.
You can either dig deeper into the website's network traffic and find the right request for your needs ( + hope you don't get banned), or you could use browser automation tools such as Selenium to grab the entire page.

Comment: yes, but the elements remains the same. Added a screenshot where it shows the elements.

Comment: The when you "inspect_element" in chrome, it loads the page source as it is when you click it (after dynamic content loading). Try using `view-source:https://www.gujaratsamachar.com/` in chrome to see what the HTML file contains before content is dynamically loaded to it - that's what you get in your http response.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests

data = ["heading", "categorySlug", "articleUrl"]



def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url).json()
    for item in r['data']:
        goal = [item[d] for d in data]
        print(goal[0], f"{url[:31]}/news/{'/'.join(goal[1:])}")


main("https://www.gujaratsamachar.com/api/stories/5993f2835b03ab694185ad25?type=top-stories")
```

Comment: @parikhparth23 you welcome, feel free to accept the answer if it's helped you by ticking the check mark beside the answer.

Comment: αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη, this code works for only those big images and not the 2 columns and 7 rows below it.